# Using iPhone7 as a microphone for MacBook

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, audio, microphone

I want my iPhone7 to be an external mic for my MacBook Pro (2015, OS 10.14.6).  I have followed this article -

https://www.macworld.com/article/2367142/understanding-the-limitations-of-a-macs-microphone.html

I’ve followed the instructions (which are very clear). And I’ve double checked. Everything seems to be right BUT the microphone is unresponsive.

Audio-MIDI setup seems fine, except I cannot adjust the ‘Master stream’ levels (this can be done with the built in mic)

Also, the ’Sounds’ preference page says that the selected device has no input controls (again, there are controls for the built-in mic).

Any suggestions please?

Comment: I’d suggest using a pair of headphones for this instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this steps:

1. Download [Microphone Live](https://apps.apple.com/it/app/microphone-live/id1070812067?l=en) on your iPhone
2. Put the iPhone in Airplane Mode (not sure why, maybe it works even without this step)
3. Connect your iPhone to your Mac with a Lightning to USB cable
4. Open Audio MIDI Setup on macOS
5. Go to Window and click on Show iOS Device Browser
6. Click Enable under your iPhone
7. Open the previously downloaded app on your iPhone
8. Open Preferences on macOS
9. Go to Sound then Input and your iPhone should appear in the list
10. Select your iPhone and you should be good to go!